# curl ftp delete mulitiple files sh script

Tags: ubuntu, curl, ftp, sh

I am trying to delete a folder with multiple files via ftp using curl (called within a sh script on ubuntu), and not having much success. I can delete an empty folder, and I can delete individual files if called directly. The thing is this is a backup folder and the names will change.
After researching it seems you can't delete multi files using the curl ftp command, and the only way is to list the files, then process the list and delete each one. But I cannot seem to find an example, can someone help me with this?

I'm using the following comamnd to list the files:

```
curl -l ftp://ftpadd/path/ --user "user:pw"
```

Comment: I'm dont khow curl can issue ftp commands. If you're connexting to a remote ftp client you should be able to use any of the commands that show up in the remote machines ftp help messages. I'm assuming you're using `del dir; del file`. Most ftps have `mdel file*`, but vary with how they support how many files `file*` can expand to. You'll need to test that part with your worst case scenarios. I had one system where I had to use `mdel A*; mdel B*;mdel C*; ...`  With the ';' char  meaning each command on a separte line in redirected input into the ftp client
help
-15 characters left

Comment: I've done a -v with curl ftp, and used -q "help", and mdel is not a valid command. I have available: < 214-The following commands are recognized.
<  ABOR ACCT ALLO APPE CDUP CWD  DELE EPRT EPSV FEAT HELP LIST MDTM MKD
<  MODE NLST NOOP OPTS PASS PASV PORT PWD  QUIT REIN REST RETR RMD  RNFR
<  RNTO SITE SIZE SMNT STAT STOR STOU STRU SYST TYPE USER XCUP XCWD XMKD
<  XPWD XRMD

Comment: curl -l ftp://server/hcbackup/ --user "id: pw" | grep ".zip"      this shows all the files in list format with zip, i just need to loop through them and do the delete using -X "DELE filename"

Answer (score 0):

called tnftp to delete the files

Comment: Please elaborate on this a little more.